# Use a bash function in a pipelined command

Tags: shell, shell-script, pipe

I have a command similar to: `... | sort -u -V`. Since some versions of `sort` do not support the `-V` flag, I thought it would be great if I made a function that conditionally adds the flag. But, it seems that my implementation does not work in a pipelined command. Here's what I've tried:

```
function sort_by_version {
    if $(sort -u -V &>/dev/null); then
        sort -u -V
    else
        sort -u
    fi
}
```

and

```
git log -n 10 --format="%s" | sort_by_version
```

How can I make this work or what other better approached are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're executing `sort` twice (once to check if the parameter is supported and then to actually run it). But what you forgot about is that your first `sort` also reads from `stdin` and therefore blocks until your actual input hits EOF (at which point there isn't any more data to read for your second `sort` instance).

Therefore redirect your first `sort`'s `stdin` (I've added parameter support (using `$@`), if you don't want that, just remove it):

```
function sort_by_version {
    if $(sort -u -V < /dev/null &>/dev/null); then
        sort -u -V "$@"
    else
        sort -u "$@"
    fi
}
```

**Edit:** added parameter support (e.g. you can use `sort_by_version -r` to reverse the results, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me tot he right direction. Works as expected now :)